# Can I control what field comes up first in the Identify Results window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, identify, results

My shapefile has 20 fields in the attribute table.

When I click "Identify results", the third text field (Welsh_Name) comes up first. Is it possible to change which field comes up first (at the top of the tree)? I would prefer to use the field "Scientific" (which as it happens is the first after ID) but it could be useful to use "Common_Nam" as well. I don't understand why this (apparently random) field has been selected to appear here.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

You can assign this field in "Layer Properties >> Display >> Field"

Comment: Great, that's all I needed to know. I'd been hunting under Layer Properties >> Field but failed to find the right place. Thanks!